# Is there a science behind precompression?

Tags: numpy, struct, compression, lzma

Here's my problem - I have a program that needs to write some output, and that output, after compression, needs to be as small as possible.

The first question one might find themselves asking in this situation is "what datastructure should i use for my data?". XML? JSON? SQLITE? TXT? STRUCT?

I think it's fairly uncontroversial to say a C-like struct is going to give you the smallest possible file *before* compression than any of the other formats, however what i'm struggling to figure out are "the rules" for designing that struct to be as small as possible *after* compression. The job of so-called 'precompression'.

By way of example, I recently had to store some DNA as compact as possible. There are 5 letters of DNA, 'A','C','G','T', and 'N'. N standing for 'dont know'. This means the smallest amount of binary to use per character is 3 bits.

```
000 = A
001 = C
010 = G
011 = T
100 = N
```

So I did what I thought was right, and wrote some code that takes a constant-length string of DNA, say four letters like 'AACA', and converts it into binary like '`000 000 001 000`' and then returns two bytes '`xxxx0000`','`00001000`' where x is padding (also 0).

The actual program took 76 letters of DNA and returns 29 bytes, but its the same idea. I then wrote these 29 bytes to a struct (of 29 uint8 bytes), with 7211405 fragments of DNA this resulted in a file of 209130745 bytes or 209Mb. After LZMA compression, this file shrunk down to 74.3Mb.

I then decided to re-run the same encoding/compression but this time encode each letter of DNA in 4 bits. Basically, every 4th bit of the previous file is now a 0. 001 becomes 0001, etc. The resultant file was 274Mb in size, so 65Mb bigger, but compressed down to 70.2Mb, or 4.1Mb smaller - a significant percentage of the final file size.

And I see the same thing with gzip, bzip2, etc. Adding the zero to get two DNA letters per byte helps the compressor out. So now what? What else could I do to help the compressor out? What else can I do to get a smaller file size (losslessly).

One trick I thought was to sort the DNA sequences to save, and have a separate key which can be used to recreate the order. In numpy this is done with

```
my_array,key = numpy.unique(original_array, return_inverse=True)
```

which makes `my_array` a sorted list of the unique items in `original_array`, and `key` which is a list of indexes of my_array that can be used to recreate `original_array`. Ideally, my_array will compress really well, as will key, but the sum of those two files is roughly that of the unsorted struct to begin with. A LITTLE smaller in some cases, a little larger in others - but nothing to write home about.

Another idea would be to use a different data structure entirely, like a graph/trei (still encoded into a struct, but each row is a node rather than an entry), but i'm concerned that i'm thinking about compression the wrong way. I know i can't reduce the filesize beyond the limits of entropy, but perhaps there are secrets to precompression like aligning data to bytes that are a better path to take than creating smaller uncompressed files - but larger compressed files.

I'm not asking *'how do you do precompression'*, I'm asking *'is precompression a thing that I can learn more about, and if so, what is the buzzword/search term I'm looking for'*.

Comment: It is a shame this was closed for being unclear/too broad. For others who Google 'precompression' and end up here, there is a great resource about it to be found here: http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know i can't reduce the filesize beyond the limits of entropy

But you can!  And lots of compressors regularly do.  The issue is that (Shannon) entropy depends on the pdf, the probability distribution of given symbols.  The symbols could be "0" or "1"; or A, C, T, G & N; or high-frequency alleles.  Each set of symbols will give you a different measure of entropy.  Find the right set of symbols and you're golden.

Compressors like LZC use various means to dynamically adjust the pdf over binary strings and are kinda hard to beat.  But if you know something about your data, you might be able to improve on them.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome!! I changed the binary values that I was assigning A/C/G/T/N around and found that my final file size (compressed) can vary quite a bit depending on what's what. Thats a really awesome trick, thank you :)
So perhaps I should look more into probability theory and Shannon entropy a bit more to learn how to make better compression